# How to synchronizing /etc/hosts files across multiple linux machines

Tags: linux, rhel, synchronization, hosts

I have 20 linux servers that use /etc/hosts files to see and talk with each other. I'm adding servers to this pool of servers.

It is required to do host resolution via the /etc/hosts files. DNS or NIS are not alternatives.

Aside from manually editing each of the 20+ /etc/hosts files every time I add a server or editing one /etc/hosts file on one server then scp'ing it to all the other servers, is there anyway to edit the /etc/hosts on one server and "push" it onto the other servers that need the new /etc/hosts file?

Comment: Put the list into a shared folder, then mount that across all the systems. On each machine, put a symlink in place from /etc/hosts to the file. One change, is seen by all. Really though, you should use DNS.

Comment: DNS or/and Ansible/Chef/Pupper https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software 

I don't understand how you manage 20 servers without using any of it.

Comment: I don't understand why DNS is not an option (care to explain?). You don't even have to have a full DNS, you could just install `avahi-daemon` and all computers can use automatically use hostname.local to talk to each other in the same segment.

Comment: sounds more complicated, but I would have a central repository (hg, git, ...), then set up a timer on each server which pulls the repository and copyies new host files to etc on change. this allows you even to rollback changes which not to much effort.

Comment: `ypcat hosts`? :)

Comment: Use the `pdcp` utility from [Parallel Distributed Shell (pdsh)](https://github.com/chaos/pdsh).  You're using RHEL, so you may be able to use the Centos package (which you can find from https://pkgs.org/download/pdsh).   If you're administering 20 servers without puppet/ansible/chef/etc you really should be using `pdsh` anyway....in fact, you should be using it even with those because it's useful for things that they're not good at (like executing simple queries on all 20 hosts).